# neo4j read parquet columnar data

Tags: neo4j, parquet

Can neo4j read parquet files directly in some way?

I have an edge list with about 20 million entries per day and would like to ingest it.

The layout is similar to:

```
id,srd,dst,timestamp,weight,rel_kind
```

And using the regular CSV way does not sound optimal.

Answer (score 0):

If by regular way you mean Neo4j's `LOAD CSV` command, what specifically doesn't seem optimal? I've used it to load very large CSVs into community edition and it has worked fine.

When dealing with a CSV as large as yours you'll need to be sure to use periodic commits to keep the transaction from running out of memory. Here's an example cut/paste from the [LOAD CSV documentation page](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-setting-the-rate-of-periodic-commits):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/csv/artists.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInteger(line[2])})
```

I usually use much larger values than 500, more like 10000 or 20000, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 0):

@hoyski `LOAD CSV` is not optimal because of the disk space required for large csvs.  Parquet is much smaller on disk, even smaller than .csv.gz when using .snappy compression.

Since Neo is based on JVM technology, and so is Parquet, it seems like a short put for Neo to add this feature.